# Parse Error on Mysqli Prepare Statement

Tags: parsing, mysqli, php

I'm getting this error when I run this code.

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'users_kudos_to_posts' (T_STRING)
```

The code.

```
if ($number > 0) {

$arr=explode(",",`$upvoted);
//If I comment out everything below I still get the error. But if I comment out
//the above code, then the error goes away.
if (in_array($primary_id, $arr)) {          
array_push($arr, $primary_id);  
$new_string = implode(",", $arr);
//the line below is where the parse error is pointing too.
   if ($stmt2 = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE `users_kudos_to_posts` SET `upvoted` = ? 
       WHERE `user_id` = ?")) {
       $stmt2->bind_param('si', $new_string, $session_user_id);
       $stmt2->execute();
       $stmt2->close(); 
   }
}
    }
```

What's crazy is that I have other multiple prepared statements in the same page of code with the same sql statement except for a change in columns and they work yet this doesn't.

Also, I ran the sql statement in phpmyAdmin and it works.

Comment: Sounds like a PHP syntax error. Maybe you did something further up. What if you comment out that line? Does the error disappear/change?

Comment: I commented out the code I showed in the question and the error still popped up. I've never seen that before.

Comment: That means that the error is further up. More than likely you've got an extra or missing quotation mark somewhere. I suggest you get a text editor that has syntax highlighting as this would likely make the error more evident.

Comment: Check the comments in the code in the question. I updated it with the results of commenting out sections.

Comment: Found it. Commenting out the sections helped. If you respond with an answer I'll give you credit for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is this line:

```
$arr=explode(",",`$upvoted);
```

You have an extra backtick that doesn't belong there. It should be:

```
$arr=explode(",",$upvoted);
```

Answer (score 0):

As StackOverflow's syntax highlighting highlights (heh), you've got an extra backtick in your `explode` statement in front of `` `$upvoted ``:

```
$arr=explode(",",`$upvoted);
```